# Request part of SVG in <img> (or <object>)

Tags: html, css, svg

Could I load only part of a SVG (that could be identified by an `#id` tag) in an `<img>` or `<object>` tag ?

Reason (if I need one) is I don't want to have two SVG files if I'm only using part of a already in use one.

If I can't by using these tags, could I by using CSS or other means ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to achieve is easiest done with another inline SVG instead of a `<img>` or `<object>` tag:

```
<svg style="width:200px;height:200px" viewBox="35 50 150 150">
    <use xlink:href="myFile.svg#head" />
</svg>
```

Two things you need to get right are

- the `viewBox`: to get just the part of your SVG that you want, you have to identify where the path is and what bounding box it has. The `<use>` element takes care that only the element you select is visible, but it does not identify *where* inside that image the element is.
- the overall size your selected element is shown at. SVG has no notion of a "natural size, you always have to give a width and height. The viewBox will then be fitted inside that area.

Comment: I guess if you combine that answer with @enxaneta 's you get something usable with an `<img>` or `<object>` tag. Thanks !

Comment: No, they do not combine in any way.

Comment: If I put your code snippet to replace his `<svg>` I would have one svg file without duplicate svg paths usable in a `<img>` tag with an #id in it's src. That answer my question and combine both of your answers, right ?

Comment: No. My snippet has the id in the `xlink:href` attribute, so it is only displaying one of the paths. It is meant to be inserted inline in your html _instead_ of using an `<img>` tag. In addition, if you reference a file that in turn references  external resources, you _must_ use an `<object>` tag. `<img>` sources need to be self-contained. (- It's "her", btw)

Comment: Ok, I get what you are saying. But stricto senso to answer my question accurately I would mix both of your answers. But you're right that directly using a `<svg>` tag is better than going with an `<img>` one (it was more an out of curiosity type of question). (- LOL, do you know each others or are you inferring that because his pseudo ends by _a_ and his profile picture's pink ?)

Comment: (- She has been referencing articles she wrote under the name "Ana Tudor" as her own.)

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at [this svg file](https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg) in view-source. Inside the root svg there are 2 other svg elements. Those 2 svg elements have an id each and the style is saying that the nestedsvg elements are visible only if `:target`.

```css
svg > svg:not(:target) {
        display: none;
}
```

```html
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100px" height="100px"  viewBox="0 0 225 225">

<style type="text/css">
 <![CDATA[  
    svg > svg:not(:target) {
    display: none;
    }
     ]]> 
</style>
<desc>
<g id="cat">
<path id="body" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M121.506,..."/>
<path id="head" fill-rule="evenodd" clip-rule="evenodd" d="M129.747,..."/>
</g>
</desc>
<svg version="1.1" id="blackcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="black" />
</svg>
<svg version="1.1" id="redcat" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" viewBox="0 0 225 225">
<use xlink:href ="#cat" fill="red" />
</svg>

</svg>
```

Here is how to use one of those svg elements as an image or as an object:

```html
<img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#redcat" width="200" />

<object width="200"  data="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/222579/cat.svg#blackcat"></object>
```

Comment: Thanks, I don't understand the `<![CDATA[ ` part nor the use of `xlink:href`. I have only one `<svg>` tag with multiple `<path>` in it, can it stay this way ?

Comment: **1.**  The `<![CDATA[`... `]]>` block is used to  indicate that the enclosed text should not be treated as markup. In this case is used to wrap the css rules. **2.**  
 Read about [the use element](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/svg/use-element.html)  **3.**  _"I have only one `<svg>` tag with multiple `<path>` in it, can it stay this way ?"_ No, You should wrap them in an svg element

Comment: In my example you can show the `redcat` or the `blackcat`

Comment: Ok, what about if I want to only show the #head because my goal isn't about changing the fill value ?

Comment: if you want to show only the head, you wrap the head inside an svg element, and you give the svg an id, for example #catshead, and you use this id for the image src: `...cat.svg#catshead`

Comment: So I would have two svg, one with #body and #head and another one with #head only ?